# How do I get the full path of a `std.fs.Dir`?

Tags: zig

Is there any way to access the full path of a `std.fs.Dir` struct? I've looked through all of the methods in the source but I can't find anything that gets path-related information on the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is `realpath`

[std.fs.Dir.realpathAlloc](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/6de0c622ff770628110208f5edeff54940cf5caa/lib/std/fs.zig#L1455)(self: Dir, allocator: Allocator, pathname: []const u8) ![]u8

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer arena.deinit();
    const alloc = arena.allocator();

    std.log.info("cwd: {s}", .{
        try std.fs.cwd().realpathAlloc(alloc, "."),
    });
}
```

realpath internally calls `std.os.getFdPath` and there doesn't seem to be any function on Dir that just does that right now.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that it would work for just having `"."` as the input path.  Thank you!